# Center align div content if font size change

Tags: html, css

My Code is like below.

```css
.wpwi_main {
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.wpwi_top {
    text-align: center;
}

.wpwi_outer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wpwi_inner {
    display: table;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}

.wpwi_row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 50%; 
}

.wpwi_row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpwi_main">
    <div class="wpwi_top">Top</div>
    <div class="wpwi_outer">
        <div>Outer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_inner">
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Time</div>
            <div>8:02 PM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Date</div>
            <div>13 Aug 2022</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Pressure</div>
            <div>999 hPa</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Visibility</div>
            <div>10000 Meter</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Cloudiness</div>
            <div>98%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunrise</div>
            <div>5:37 AM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunset</div>
            <div>6:39 PM</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to keep two columns as close as possible without line break and center aligned when font size increase or decrease. I would like to keep like this image when font size is 28px https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYOzI.png and I would like to keep like this image when font size is 9px https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Jc3.png

Comment: Are you stuck with that HTML or can you change the structure?

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth. Yes, I can change HTML structure. Thanks.

Comment: As your data is genuinely tabular why not display it as an HTML table?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to unset `width: 40%` on `.wpwi_inner` and increase the width of `.wpwi_row > div` from 20% to 60%.

```css
.wpwi_main {
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.wpwi_top {
    text-align: center;
}

.wpwi_outer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wpwi_inner {
    display: table;
    /* width: 40%; */ /* Removed this */
    margin: auto;
}

.wpwi_row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 50%; 
}

.wpwi_row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 60%; /*Increase this width to 60%*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wpwi_main">
    <div class="wpwi_top">Top</div>
    <div class="wpwi_outer">
        <div>Outer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_inner">
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Time</div>
            <div>8:02 PM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Date</div>
            <div>13 Aug 2022</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Pressure</div>
            <div>999 hPa</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Visibility</div>
            <div>10000 Meter</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Cloudiness</div>
            <div>98%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunrise</div>
            <div>5:37 AM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunset</div>
            <div>6:39 PM</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```